# Dietpi - How to upgrade my kernel version to latest version

Tags: linux, kernel, arm

I had odroid-xu4 with [DietPi](http://dietpi.com/) OS on it.

My current kernel version; `uname -a`:

```
Linux DietPi 3.10.106+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 24 16:26:38 CET 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I'm trying to install tp-link TL-WN822N wifi device driver. But it asks me to upgrade my kernel version to 3.10 to 4.*.

I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
```

and

```
sudo apt-get update
```

also i tried:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

It installed correctly but i run `uname -a`.It gives the same out as `Linux DietPi 3.10.106+ #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Nov 24 16:26:38 CET 2017 armv7l GNU/Linux`
When i finally restart my odroid,it cannnot boot.

So,can anyone tell me a correct procedure to upgrade my kernel and how to change `uname -a` output to show a upgraded kernel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please keep back up of your important files before the upgrade. Please read this [XU4 kernel upgrade](http://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2399)

**Solution 1:**

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

**Solution 2:**

If `dist-upgrade` does not work then please try removing conflicting 3.x package before install:

```
sudo apt-get purge linux-image-3*
```

**Do not reboot system, until below is installed.**

```
sudo apt-get install linux-image-4.9-armhf-odroid-xu3
```

**Solution 3:**  [[Solved] XU4 kernel upgrade from 3.10 to 4.9](http://dietpi.com/phpbb/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=1935#)

Download the `.deb` file

```
wget https://oph.mdrjr.net/meveric/kernel/XU3/4.9.x/linux-image-4.9.29+_4.9.29-20170527-XU3_armhf.deb  -O package.deb
```

install the `.deb` file using `dpkg`

```
dpkg -i package.deb
```

Comment: If this answer solves your problem, please accept the answer by clicking the answer button. Or, If you would have solved by yourself, please share the solution.

Comment: i updated my odroid kernel by using these commands 'apt-cache search linux-headers'
'apt-get install linux-headers-4.14-armhf-odroid-xu4'
'apt-cache search linux-image'
'linux-image-4.14-armhf-odroid-xu4'. then reboot

Comment: i tried your steps but it makes my device to not booting @Dipankar Nalui